# GDB crashing - UNEXPECTED GDB STDERR: Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding

Tags: python, c++, debugging, gdb

I am using QtCreator in ubuntu(virtual box) to run a simple c++ program(hello.cpp). The QtCreator is building and running the application fine .But when it is not letting me to debug. I am running a shell script on ubuntu of vbox to get some cross compilers required, since i have a hard ware which holds arm architecture. finally i want to push the cross compiled executable on to the hardware and do remote debugging. Before that i am trying to perfrom desktop debugging on ubuntu, but the GDB is crashing. I think GDB is getting confused with some python path. Can anyone help me with this?
Here is the picture of GDB log:

[image: GDB log]

Answer (score 0):

This error most likely means that Python isn't installed properly on your machine.  This error comes during gdb initialization, when it tries to initialize the Python interpreter.  If `Py_Initialize` fails, there isn't much gdb can do about it...

Comment: The python is installed properly. But the worrying thing is some how GDB is getting confused with python paths. My shell script which installs all cross compilers and other stuff holds files like python 2.7. when i ran this shell script, it is setting up some folders which holds a file with all path variables. The QtCreator shell script is pointing to the file which holds all these paths. My Qt is pointing to these folders installed by shell script instead of my ubuntu python paths. What is the initial step to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to gdb optimization environment variables. there are 4 variables in in the ide, configured with -o2 optimization. Remove the -o2 optimization in the front of variables, then it will resolve your issue. In my case its -o2, in your case, it can be other optimizations. Please look for them.